# Binary arithmetic

Tags: math-mode

Is there a package to perform binary arithmetic like addition, subtraction, and so on? Ex: 1101 + 0001 = 1110.

BUT not as text, like I've typed in here!

Also, is there any other packager rather than **xlop** for decimal arithmetic operations?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  What do you mean by "BUT not as text"?

Comment: This should be easy with LuaTeX.

Answer (score 20):

The math functions built into `pgf` can be used:

[image]

### Notes:

- An integer with prefix `0b` or `0B` is interpreted as a binary number and is automatically converted to base 10.  Hence the prefixes in `0b#1 + 0b#2`.
  It should be noted that this feature of treating numbers with a leading `0` as an octal number can **not** be disabled as per
  Martin Scharrer's answer at [Unexpected results from pgfmath functions with numbers with leading 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52232/unexpected-results-from-pgfmath-functions-with-numbers-with-leading-0).
- `\pgfmathbin{x}` converts an integer to a binary representation.
- `\pgfmathprintnumber` is optional and is used to format the number. In this case it automatically detects that the decimal value of the addition is an integer and produces `102` instead of `102.0` as is the case for the first decimal addition.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand{\BinaryAdd}[2]{%
    {#1}_2 + {#2}_2 = \pgfmathbin{0b#1 + 0b#2}% compute binary addition
    \pgfmathresult_2% format output to make it clear it is base 2
}%
\newcommand{\BinarySub}[2]{%
    {#1}_2 - {#2}_2 = \pgfmathbin{0b#1 - 0b#2}% compute binary subtraction
    \pgfmathresult_2% format output to make it clear it is base 2
}%

\newcommand{\DecimalAdd}[2]{%
    #1 + #2 = \pgfmathparse{#1 + #2}%    compute addition
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}% format output
}%
\newcommand{\DecimalSub}[2]{%
    #1 - #2 = \pgfmathparse{#1 - #2}%    compute subtraction
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}% format output
}%
\begin{document}
$\BinaryAdd{101}{0001}$\par
$\BinarySub{101}{0001}$

\bigskip
$\DecimalAdd{101}{0001}$\par
$\DecimalSub{101}{0001}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`fmtcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) allows for a variety of counter formatting options, including printing decimal values as binary (with some leading zeros, if needed).

The following minimal example provides `\binnum[<width>]{<num>}` the prints `<num>` in binary of width `<width>` (default is `4`), and allows for calculations. For proper spacing, it should be used in math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\textwidth}{400pt}% Just for this example
\usepackage{fmtcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount
\newcounter{mycounter}%
\newcommand{\binnum}[2][4]{%
  \setcounter{mycounter}{\numexpr #2\relax}%
  \padzeroes[#1]{\binary{mycounter}}%
}
\begin{document}
$13+1=\binnum{13}_2+\binnum{1}_2=\binnum{13+1}_2$ \par
$1+2+4+8+16+32=\binnum{1}_2+\binnum{2}_2+\binnum{4}_2+\binnum{8}_2+\binnum{16}_2+\binnum{32}_2=\binnum[8]{1+2+4+8+16+32}_2$
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

If you're interested, you can use this updated version that defines a starred version of `\binnum[*][<width>]{<num>}`. The defaults are the same with the unstarred version printing the base (2) as well. The starred version does not print the base:

```
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\binnum}{s O{4} m}{%
  \setcounter{mycounter}{\numexpr #3\relax}%
  \padzeroes[#2]{\binary{mycounter}}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{_2}%
}
```

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides the command definition interface.

Answer (score 6):

As usual, I recommend `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ci}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\numa}{33.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\numb}{15.4}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|} \hline
 & add & sub & mult & div \\
decimal & \ci{\numa+\numb} & \ci{\numa-\numb} & \ci{\numa*\numb} & \ci{\numa/\numb} \\ \hline
binary & \ci{bin(\numa+\numb)} & \ci{bin(\numa-\numb)} & \ci{bin(\numa*\numb)} & \ci{bin(\numa/\numb)} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's not exactly tikz but rather pgfmath

Comment: Yeah, but I end up always putting `\usepackage{tikz}` in my preamble

Answer (score 2):

The following implements some of the functions for using radix 2 numbers as input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:cpn {@binary} #1 { \int_to_binary:n { #1 } } % necessary for LaTeX2e infrastructure

\cs_new:Npn \binary_sum:nn #1 #2
  {
   \int_eval:n { \int_from_binary:n { #1 } + \int_from_binary:n { #2 } }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\evalbinsum}{ m m }
  {
   \int_to_binary:n { \binary_sum:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\binsetcounter}{ m m }
  {
   \setcounter{#1}{\int_from_binary:n {#2}}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\showbinsum}{ m m }
  {
   #1_2 + #2_2 = \evalbinsum{#1}{#2}_2
  }

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\binary}[1]{\expandafter\@binary\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\showbinsum{1101}{0001}$ % show a sum of radix 2 numbers

\newcounter{mycnt}

\binsetcounter{mycnt}{11001} % set a counter using a radix 2 number

$\arabic{mycnt}=\binary{mycnt}_2$ % verification

\end{document}
```

With `\binary{mycnt}` one gets the radix 2 representation of the counter's value (similar to `\arabic`).

Comment: Shouldn't the `\ExplSyntaxOff` come after the def of `\showbinsum`? No big deal since that's used in math mode, just a little weird.

Comment: There's `_` in the definition of `\showbinsum`. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm silly. <tongue-in-cheek> You could use `\c_math_subscript_token` (I think that's the name). </tongue-in-cheek>

Comment: Since it's defined only in terms of other document commands, I think it's simpler in this way.