# Unexpected results from pgfmath functions with numbers with leading 0

Tags: pgfmath

The pgfmath functions give me unexpected results when used on numbers with leading zeros. Are the output in the example below expected for `0011` and `0021`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\truncateline[2]{% 
    #1 & #2 & \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\foo}{#1}\foo \\%
}
\newcommand\roundline[2]{% 
    #1 & #2 & \pgfmathround{#1}\pgfmathresult \\%
}
\newcommand\intline[2]{% 
    #1 & #2 & \pgfmathint{#1}\pgfmathresult \\%
}

\begin{document}

\section{pgfmathtruncatemacro}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Input & Expected & Output \\
\truncateline{0}{0}
\truncateline{1}{1}
\truncateline{01}{1}
\truncateline{001}{1}
\truncateline{0011}{11}
\truncateline{0021}{21}
\end{tabular}

\section{pgfmathround}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Input & Expected & Output \\
\roundline{0}{0}
\roundline{1}{1}
\roundline{01}{1}
\roundline{001}{1}
\roundline{0011}{11}
\roundline{0021}{21}
\end{tabular}

\section{pgfmathint}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Input & Expected & Output \\
\intline{0}{0}
\intline{1}{1}
\intline{01}{1}
\intline{001}{1}
\intline{0011}{11}
\intline{0021}{21}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `pgfmanual` states (section 62.1 *Commands for Parsing Expressions*, page 526 with v2.10):

> An integer with a zero-prefix (excluding, of course zero itself), is interpreted as an octal number and is automatically converted to base 10.

So `021` or `0021` is actually 2x8+2x1 = 17, not 21.

You would need to avoid or remove the leading 0s, e.g. using a recursive macro like:

```
\def\removeleadingzeros#1{\if0#1 \expandafter\removeleadingzeros\else#1\fi}
```

This however doesn't work in the general case (breaks e.g. with only `0` or `00` etc.). Expanding the number with `\the\numexpr <number>\relax` would also turn e.g. `0021` into `21`, but this would of course limit the usefulness of using `pgfmath` in the first place.

---

After searching the manual and looking at the source code of `pgfmathparser.code.tex` this behavior seems to be hard coded and is not configurable.

Comment: In my case I am expecting integer input (possibly with leading 0). Appending a `.0` to the input causes pgf to interpret the numbers in base 10 irrespective of the leading 0. `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\foo}{0021.0}\foo` gives `21` as desired.

Comment: Martin can you elaborate on why using `\the\numexpr <number>\relax` would limit the usefulness of using `\pgfmath`. This seems to be working for me but just wanted to make sure that there is not some other problem with this.  Also, using `\pgfmathparse{\removeleadingzeros{31} - \removeleadingzeros{07}}\pgfmathresult` yields `Argument of \removeleadingzeros has an extra }.`, but works fine if I replaced the `07` with just `7`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: In that case `<number>` can only by a valid `numexpr`, so all advanced `pgfmath` expressions are no longer allowed.