# Section numbering in binary

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Is it possible to number sections by binary numbers, starting at 0?  So `\section{First Section}` would render as "0. First Section", and the next instance would render "1. Second Section" and the third, "10. Third Section"?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Binary arithmetic](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/42515) (for your specific applications, the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42518/2693) which uses the the `fmtcount` package seems the most appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_set:Npn \thesection {\int_to_bin:n{\value{section}-1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{one}

\section{two}

\section{three}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Note that I only changed the *displayed* number here, so the `section` counter still has the value `1` for the first section, we only print `0`. If you want the section to "really" have the number `0`, you need to remove the `-1` from the definition of `\thesection` and set the counter to `-1` at the start of the document.

Answer (score 11):

The `fmtcount` package provides a simple way to get the binary numbers. To begin counting at zero you need to set the section counter initially to `-1`. You can also pad the values with zeroes if you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\binary{section}.}
\setcounter{section}{-1}% To begin at 0

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
\section{Fifth section}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\padzeroes[4]\binary{section}}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
\section{Fifth section}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: This has the big disadvantage of not being expandable.